# Unable to compile LIBNETFILTER_QUEUE

Tags: compiler-construction, netfilter

I just downloaded libnfnetlink and libnetfilter_queue tarballs.

After succesfully compiling, libnfnetlink is installed (make installed) and I can see it under /usr/lib (set to my LD_LIBRARY_PATH)

```
[root@pcen] libnetfilter_queue]# ls -l /usr/lib/libnf
libnfnetlink.so.0      libnfsidmap.la         libnfsidmap.so.0.2.0
libnfnetlink.so.0.2.0  libnfsidmap.so.0
```

But when I builds libnetfilter_queue; I keep on getting this error:

```
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for LIBNFNETLINK... no
configure: error: Cannot find libnfnetlink >= 0.0.41
```

So could you please point out what’s going on? I tried to look for additional documentation but couldn’t find where was the problem.

I will very much appreciate your help. Regards

Comment: Did the pkgconfig files of libnfnetlink get installed properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your libnfnetlink.pc files are in /usr/lib/pkgconfig, try this:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/pkgconfig
./configure
```

I had a similar problem (except I installed into /usr/local).